# Click on “R more” button on mouthshut.com reviews using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scroll through http://www.mouthshut.com/mobile-operators/Reliance-Jio-reviews-925812061 page. I need to click on the "Read MORE" button in review section, but I can't find it with using beautiful soup in python..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup can parse the html but it can't click the links. Selenium can click the links though.

```
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.mouthshut.com/mobile-operators/Reliance-Jio-reviews-925812061-page-{}'.format
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url(1))
for elem in driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Read More'):
    elem.click()
    sleep(0.5)

with open('page_source.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)
driver.close()
```

After you have saved the source html from each page, you can then use BeautifulSoup to parse through it and extract whatever you want.

---

EDIT: Adding in `sleep(0.5)` after clicking each link seemed to get rid of the errors where some of the "Read More" links weren't being clicked.

Comment: @priyankamane No problem, happy to help! Hopefully you can mark it as the accepted answer then.

Comment: Hello G_M I am getting this error when tried above code: WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home. Can you please suggest how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Tried to run the code suggested by G_M but got an error. But solved it using the following steps:

Platform: Using Windows 10, Anaconda-Jupyter Notebook, Chrome browser.

1. Step 1: installed selenium using the following command in Jupyter notebook:

   !pip install selenium
2. Step 2: executed the code by G_M above: it showed me the following error:

   WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home.
3. Downloaded chromedriver from the link provided in the error message: from the mentioned link downloaded the latest version of chromedriver. It's a zip file. unzip the file you will get an .exe file,  upload it to the same location/folder where the Jupyter notebook is running.
4. Restart the notebook. And execute the code again. It's working fine now.

I am using this code to expand the comments by clicking 'Read More' link in the review web page for a product. The code it's working fine except for the 1st comment it was not expanded completely. I don't know why but the code is working fine on other comments.